# Recognize logo in a bitmap - android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I'd like to detect if a logo image in user's camera view - for example if the logo of StackOverflow was printed on a paper and viewed through camera. Or for less complicated approach let's say that I'd like to detect it in a bitmap. I'd like to recognize if one specific logo - it's possible to hardcode it to the app.

Is it even possible with using of open-source libraries like OpenCV or would it require lots and lots of man-hours to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with opencv but might still require lots and lots of man-hours depending on your definition of lots and lots.

On a more serious note: start at [template matching](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html). If that is not enough for you perhaps [SIFT features are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749299/training-sift-features-in-opencv). Also, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image%20matching) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=template%20matching) [site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcomputer-vision%5D%20matching&submit=search), there are some pretty good discussions about stuff like this to be found.

Comment: opencv is C, and this means native mode in android -  means major PITA. it is also way too big - user acceptance for 10MB big apps is  very limited

Comment: @jilles - lots and lots are tens of hours - compared to something in plug and play fashion. As the entire rest of the project would take maybe 6 hours and template matching/sift/surf would take 60 hours, I don't think it's a good idea to start working on this

Answer (score 2):

This is a clear case for  invariant moments matching (look into wikipedia about Hu Moments). And I'm developing  free opensource library which uses it for text tecognition on android:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

There are android demos,  demonsrtating complete roundtrip - sampling, training and recognition.   Here is market application showcasing  it:

https://market.android.com/details?id=de.pribluda.android.ocrcall&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImRlLnByaWJsdWRhLmFuZHJvaWQub2NyY2FsbCJd

( Support for the library through mailing lists )

I would say, that implementing recognition for just one logo will take me anout 5-6 hours.

Addition: OpenCV is a big library writen in C, and just integrate it into android is major PITA